Error On Unused Addition With Random Attached
So today I was doing a Python test which envolved encryption, I did some debugging. None of it worked though. Can you guys help me? This is the whole piece:
import random

LONEK = input("Type Your Words Here ") #Letter Or Number Encryption Key

LONEKL = len(LONEK) #Letter Or Number Encryption Key Length

for REAPEAT in range(LONEKL):

    if 'A' in LONEK:
        A = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'a' in LONEK:
        a = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'B' in LONEK:
        B = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'b' in LONEK:
        b = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'C' in LONEK:
        C = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'c' in LONEK:
        c = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'D' in LONEK:
        D = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'd' in LONEK:
        d = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'E' in LONEK:
        E = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'e' in LONEK:
        e = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'F' in LONEK:
        F = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'f' in LONEK:
        f = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'G' in LONEK:
        G = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'g' in LONEK:
        g = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'H' in LONEK:
        H = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'h' in LONEK:
        h = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'I' in LONEK:
        I = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'i' in LONEK:
        i = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'J' in LONEK:
        J = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'j' in LONEK:
        j = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'K' in LONEK:
        K = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'k' in LONEK:
        k = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'L' in LONEK:
        L = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'l' in LONEK:
        l = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'M' in LONEK:
        M = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'm' in LONEK:
        m = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'N' in LONEK:
        N = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'n' in LONEK:
        n = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'O' in LONEK:
        O = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'o' in LONEK:
        o = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'P' in LONEK:
        P = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'p' in LONEK:
        p = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'Q' in LONEK:
        Q = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'q' in LONEK:
        q = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'R' in LONEK:
        R = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'r' in LONEK:
        r = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'S' in LONEK:
        S = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 's' in LONEK:
        s = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'T' in LONEK:
        T = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 't' in LONEK:
        t = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'U' in LONEK:
        U = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'u' in LONEK:
        u = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'V' in LONEK:
        V = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'v' in LONEK:
        v = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'W' in LONEK:
        W = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'w' in LONEK:
        w = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'X' in LONEK:
        X = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'x' in LONEK:
        x = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'Y' in LONEK:
        Y = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'y' in LONEK:
        y = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'Z' in LONEK:
        Z = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'z' in LONEK:
        z = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if "~" in LONEK:
        C1 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '`' in LONEK:
        C2 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '!' in LONEK:
        C3 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '@' in LONEK:
        C4 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '#' in LONEK:
        C5 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '$' in LONEK:
        C6 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '%' in LONEK:
        C7 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '^' in LONEK:
        C8 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '&' in LONEK:
        C9 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '*' in LONEK:
        C10 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '(' in LONEK:
        C11 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if ')' in LONEK:
        C12 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '<' in LONEK:
        C13 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if ',' in LONEK:
        C14 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '>' in LONEK:
        C15 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '.' in LONEK:
        C16 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '?' in LONEK:
        C17 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '/' in LONEK:
        C18 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if ':' in LONEK:
        C19 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if ';' in LONEK:
        C20 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '"' in LONEK:
        C21 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if "'" in LONEK:
        C22 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '{' in LONEK:
        C23 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '[' in LONEK:
        C24 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '}' in LONEK:
        C25 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if ']' in LONEK:
        C26 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '|' in LONEK:
        C27 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '-' in LONEK:
        C28 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '_' in LONEK:
        C29 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '+' in LONEK:
        C30 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '=' in LONEK:
        C31 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '1' in LONEK:
        C32 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '2' in LONEK:
        C33 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '3' in LONEK:
        C34 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '4' in LONEK:
        C35 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '5' in LONEK:
        C36 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '6' in LONEK:
        C37 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '7' in LONEK:
        C38 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '8' in LONEK:
        C39 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '9' in LONEK:
        C40 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if '0' in LONEK:
        C41 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if ' ' in LONEK:
        C42 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    else:
        C43 = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

LONEKF = A+a+B+b+C+c+D+d+E+e+F+f+G+g+H+h+I+i+J+j+K+k+L+l+M+m+N+n+O+o+P+p+Q+q+R+r+S+s+T+t+U+u+V+v+W+w+X+x+Y+y+Z+z+C1+C2+C3+C4+C5+C6+C7+C8+C9+C10+C11+C12+C13+C14+C15+C16+C17+C18+C19+C20+C21+C22+C23+C24+C25+C26+C27+C28+C29+C30+C31+C32+C33+C34+C35+C36+C37+C38+C39+C40+C41+C42+C43

All The Letters Added Up
print(f'Your Encryption Code Is: {LONEKF}') 

I suspected it to go through, and it gave me an error but I couldn't figure it out. This is the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/BLANK/PycharmProjects/Encription Test/EF.py", line 294, in <module>
    LONEKF = A+a+B+b+C+c+D+d+E+e+F+f+G+g+H+h+I+i+J+j+K+k+L+l+M+m+N+n+O+o+P+p+Q+q+R+r+S+s+T+t+U+u+V+v+W+w+X+x+Y+y+Z+z+C1+C2+C3+C4+C5+C6+C7+C8+C9+C10+C11+C12+C13+C14+C15+C16+C17+C18+C19+C20+C21+C22+C23+C24+C25+C26+C27+C28+C29+C30+C31+C32+C33+C34+C35+C36+C37+C38+C39+C40+C41+C42+C43
             ^
NameError: name 'A' is not defined


if you encrypt in this way.  How do you propose to decrypt ?

"Couldn't figure it out". Perhaps think of it this way: I ask you to add 'Apple + House', what is the result?  Your answer is likely, 'I don't know, you haven't told be the values of Apple nor House'.  Well, this is exactly what Python is saying to you.  'You'll haven't told be the value of A', etc. You need to define initial values, first.

@D.L - This doesn't appear to be encryption, but rather key generation. So a one-way hash is ok.

@s3dev: Except it's not even a hash. A hash would be meaningfully based on the input. The only way in which this (or a fixed version of this) is based on the input is that it will sum a greater number of random numbers if there are more unique printable ASCII letters in the input, and regenerate each of them pointlessly over and over based on the input length. One-way hash implies that, given the same input, you could produce the same output (you just can't go from output back to input); in this case, the exact same input would at best produce roughly the same mean value if run many times.

@ShadowRanger - Yes, true point given a hash is repeatable; whereas this logic is certainly not.

Although there are many problems I can pinpoint with the code you've posted, the error you're currently facing - as others have mentioned - is that since the expression under any of the if statements may or may not get executed when you're actually summing over all of your variables since they are never being defined in their respective if statement, so the interpreter knows nothing about them and throws this error.

You're on the right track, but this has absolutely nothing to do with scope, as all variables are in the global space, due to the lack of functions and classes. The problem here is exactly what the error message states - the variables are not defined; because, as you mention, the statement under the given if has not been executed.

@s3dev you're right I'll edit my answer.

The reason:
The error message NameError: name 'A' is not defined is exceedingly clear once you understand it, or think about it a bit.
Perhaps think of it this way: I ask you to add Apple + House, what is the result? Your answer is likely, 'I don't know, you haven't told be the values of Apple nor House'. Exactly! Well, this is exactly what Python is saying to you. 'You'll haven't told be the value of A', etc. You need to define initial values, first.
Well, that's a lot of initialisation (95 values to be exact). A lot, especially given the key chosen by the user will likely not use all 95 characters, perhaps only 15 at the most. So why initialise all of them?  No need.  Especially given a different random value is assigned each time the program is run.

Another approach:
What you've done can be distilled into the following code, which can be simplified even further, but I decided against this to keep the code clear.

Prompt the user for their phrase.
Only generate a random integer (bound to [0,99] for brevity) for the characters in the phrase - no more, no less. This line of code uses a Python technique known as dictionary comprehension.
Calculate the sum for the key based on the lookup, defined in the statement above.
Display the results.

Example code:
import random

# Prompt the user.
phrase = input('Enter a phrase: ')

# Create a lookup of {character: random integer}
values = {c: random.randint(0, 99) for c in phrase}
# Calculate the summed result.
key = sum(values.get(c) for c in phrase)

# Display the results and debugging information.
print(phrase, values, key)

Example output:
>>> Enter a key: abcABCabc

abcABCabc  # Phrase 
{'a': 77, 'b': 92, 'c': 98, 'A': 29, 'B': 58, 'C': 96}  # Lookup
717  # Key


Other considerations:

This algorithm is exceedingly insecure, given the potential collision rate and ease to reverse engineer.
This is not an encryption algorithm, but more specifically, a key generation algorithm. The encryption (and decryption) will use this key, in some manner.
It must be said that if you're looking to roll your own key algorithm, or encryption algorithm, don't.  Leave that to the pros, because of the complex mathematics involved and the mature nature of the science. However, if this is just an educational exercise ... crack on mate!  But try and learn more secure techniques as you move forward.


Minor improvement: Given order doesn't matter, you could skip the dict and just uniquify the input and generate that many times. key = sum(random.randrange(100) for _ in set(phrase)). Or push more work to random with key = sum(random.choices(range(100), k=len(set(phrase)))). (On top of that, using the secrets module is the way to do this for cryptographic purposes, but this is hopelessly broken for those purposes no matter how you do it)

@ShadowRanger - Thanks for the tip.  However, the suggested improvement does not account for a phrase with repeated characters. One assumption made from the OP's post, is that if a character is repeated, it must retain the same random value. Hence, why I used a dict for lookup.

It doesn't retain it, to be clear (both your code and the OP's replace it each loop). That said, the final combination step is addition, where the order doesn't matter anyway, so you could generate rather fewer random values with the same (lack of) security.

Apologies, I misspoke.  A repeated character's random value is not retained (you're correct) it is overwritten in each loop. However, In the example of 'abca' when summing from a set the sum would only add a+b+c, whereas a+b+c+a should be added to produce the 'correct' sum. Therefore summing from a set, would be 'inaccurate'.  However, a set could be used in the dict comp, to reduce the number of calls to random ... but I feel that's a bit performance nitty-gritty for an already  broken algorithm.  :-)

There are some problems with your approach, but the best way to fix the problem you're having right now is to declare all the letter variables outside of the if statements.
import random

LONEK = input("Type Your Words Here ") #Letter Or Number Encryption Key

LONEKL = len(LONEK) #Letter Or Number Encryption Key Length

A = a = B = b = ... = 0

for REAPEAT in range(LONEKL):

    if 'A' in LONEK:
        A = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'a' in LONEK:
        a = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'B' in LONEK:
        B = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'b' in LONEK:
        b = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'C' in LONEK:
        C = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'c' in LONEK:
        c = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    if 'D' in LONEK:
        D = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    ...

If you want to simplify all the if statements you have, you can do something like the following:
from string import printable

LONEK = input("Type Your Words Here ") #Letter Or Number Encryption Key

LONEKL = len(LONEK) #Letter Or Number Encryption Key Length

mappings = {c: 0 for c in printable}

for REAPEAT in range(LONEKL):
    for c in LONEK:
        mappings[c] += random.randint(1, 999...)

LONEKF = sum(mappings.values())

Also a quick note, setting A = random.randint... for each REAPEAT is kind of redundant as it overwrites the value for A you had on the previous iteration of the for loop.
